# Identifying before and after with fixed point (Loop)

Tags: php

Trying to create a reusable function to recreate an array like such:

```
$page_step_steps = array(
  array("id" => "1", "step" => "done-step"),
  'main-active-step next-step-five',
  array("id" => "2", "step" => "done-step"),
  "main-active-step next-step-five",
  array("id" => "3", "step" => "active-step"),
  "main-next-step next-step-five",
  array("id" => "4", "step" => "next-step"),
  "main-next-step next-step-five",
  array("id" => "5", "step" => "next-step")
);
```

I am currently stuck on identifying the everything **ABOVE** the active step and **BELOW** the active step, and give them the correct step ID

**i.e.** everything above the `active-step` needs to have a `done-step` assigned to the `step` value and the array underneath it should have `main-active-step`.

However, everything underneath it should have `next-step` and `main-next-step`.

**Sandbox link to try it out:** http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c4b85c3d038560d8d3b4b5ad372f67a22df785c1

**Here is the function so far:**

```
function formatting_steps($step, $steps){
  $page_step_steps = array();
  $steps_t = array(1 => "one", 2 => "two", 3 => "three", 4 => "four", 5 => "five", 6 => "six");
  $steps_f = $steps_t[$steps];
  $final_steps = $steps * 2;

  for($i = 1; $i < $final_steps; $i++){

    $r_step = round($i / 2, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);

    if($i % 2){
      if($i == 1){
        $page_step_steps[$i]['id'] = $i;

        if($i == $step){
          $page_step_steps[$i]['step'] = "active-step";
        }
        else {
          $page_step_steps[$i]['step'] = $i;
        }
      }
      else {
        $page_step_steps[$i]['id'] = $r_step;

        if($r_step == $step){
          $page_step_steps[$i]['step'] = "active-step";
        }
        else {
          $page_step_steps[$i]['step'] = $i;
        }
      }
    }
    else {
      $page_step_steps[] = 'next-step-' . $steps_f;     
    }

  }

  $page_step_steps = $page_step_steps;

  return $page_step_steps;  
}
```

**Output so far:**

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [step] => 1
        )

    [2] => next-step-four
    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [step] => 3
        )

    [4] => next-step-four
    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [step] => active-step
        )

    [6] => next-step-four
    [7] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [step] => 7
        )

)
```

---

EDIT: Passing the following in the function : `formatting_steps(3, 4);`

Comment: what is the parameters for `formatting_steps` function? please specify.

Comment: okey got it..........

Comment: can you please explain what `3, 4` do???

Comment: did you want something like [this](https://3v4l.org/QKYic)

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at your function, you have an statement that identifies the `active` state.

If you focus on the `else` statement, you can do the following

```
if($step > $i){
    $page_step_steps[$i]['step'] = "done-step";             
}
else{               
    $page_step_steps[$i]['step'] = "next-step";
}
```

and

```
if($step > $r_step){
    $page_step_steps[$i]['step'] = "done-step";             
}
else{
    $page_step_steps[$i]['step'] = "next-step";
}
```